# react-router pass props to component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have these two components, Application and Landing. I want to pass the currentUser down to the Landing component, but the props don't get passed with my current setup. Is this possible to do with react-router v4. I'm trying not to use redux. I just want to be able to pass my logged in to a few components that will have different routes.

**Application.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { auth, database } from '../firebase';
import { HashRouter, Match } from 'react-router';
import Landing from './Landing';
import SignIn from './SignIn';

import map from 'lodash/map';

class Application extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentUser: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((currentUser) => {
      console.log('AUTH_CHANGE', currentUser);
      this.setState({ currentUser });

      // redirect to dashboard? 

    });
  }

  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="Application">
        <header className="Application--header">
          <h1>Site Title</h1>
        </header>

        <HashRouter>
          <div>
            <Match exactly pattern='/' component={Landing} user={currentUser} />
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Application;
```

**Landing.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { auth, database } from '../firebase';
import CurrentUser from './CurrentUser';
import SignIn from './SignIn';

class Landing extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() { 
        const currentUser = this.props.user;  

        return (
            <div>
                {!currentUser && <SignIn />}
                {
                  currentUser && 
                  <div>
                    <CurrentUser user={currentUser} />
                  </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you could pass it by wrapping your component for example `<Match exactly pattern='/' component={(props) => (<Landing {...props} />)} user={currentUser} />`, i'm curious as well.

Comment: You can pass props to components in `react-router` by using the `render` function: `<Route path="/" render={() => <Landing user={currentUser} />} />`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this one. hope this will help you:
`<ProtectedRoute user={userStore} path="/transfers/own-card/accepted/:transaction_id" exact component={(props) => (<PaymentCheckPage infoPage={true} {...props} />)} />`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `render` prop in the Route component (as KA01 pointed out in the comments). There you can provide a function that returns the component, and you can also pass the props that you want:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={props => <Landing {...props} currentUser={currentUser} />} />
```